# Jackson Deserialization of custom POJO

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a Pojo which looks like this:

```
public class LdapUserImpl implements LdapUser
{

  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /** The action. */
  private String action;

  private Map<String, String> translation;

  /** The fields. */
  private List<Map<String, String>> fields;

  public LdapUserImpl()
  {
    /* nothing special needed */
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public String getAction()
  {
    return action;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getTranslation()
  {
    return translation;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public List<Map<String, String>> getFields()
  {
    return fields;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void setAction( String action )
  {
    this.action = action;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void setTranslation( Map<String, String> translation )
  {
    this.translation = translation;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void setFields( List<Map<String, String>> data )
  {
    this.fields = data;
  }

}
```

So it basically contains a *String*, a *Map* and a *List*.

when I try to read this json:

```
[
{
  'action': 'New User',
  'translation': 
  {
    'key': 'ldap.action.new',
    'value': 'ldap.action.new' 
  },
  'fields': 
  [
   { 
     'emailAddress': 'email',
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   {
     'enabled': 'TRUE',
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   { 
     'firstName': 'First', 
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   { 
     'lastName': 'Last',
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   {
     'name': 'FirstL',
     'changed': 'false'
   }
  ]
 },
 { 
   'action': 'New User',
   'translation':
   {
     'key': 'ldap.action.new',
     'value': 'ldap.action.new' 
   }, 
   'fields': 
   [
   {
     'emailAddress': 'email2',
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   {
     'enabled': 'TRUE', 
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   {
     'firstName': 'First2',
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   {
     'lastName': 'Last2',
     'changed': 'false'
   },
   {
     'name': 'FirstL2', 
     'changed': 'false'
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

with this Method:

```
CollectionType typeReference = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType( List.class, LdapUser.class );
List<LdapUser> ldapUser = objectMapper.readValue( (String) data.get(RESULT_DATA ), typeReference );
```

If you are wondering why I cast *data.get* to *String* it is because I get the **json** as a `Map<String, Object>` but can only cast to String since casting to something else causes an exception most of the times.

The exception I receive looks like this:

> "messageKey": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
>     "message": "Can not construct instance of com.company.api.data.authn.LdapUser, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: {JSON} (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])",
>     "returnType": "FATAL"

The Object LdapUser is Serializable, so I don't get the problem which Jackson states to me.

Comment: `LdapUser` is an interface, not a `concrete type`, as error states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `LdapUser.class` for the `typeReference`.

You need to use a concrete type here like `LdapUserImpl.class`, because interfaces don't have fields or method implementations, so it can't read your getter and setters.

Comment: Ok so he doesn't retrieve the standard implementation by itself?

Comment: There is no "standard implemenation" for an interface. You wrote that yourself...